# Optimizing javascript for auto scroll feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

Knowing only enough javascript and jquery to be dangerous, I cargo-culted some javascript code for a table of contents in a left sidebar that corresponds to the content in a content area. The table of contents scrolls automatically to reflect where in the content the user is. You can see a [live demo here.](http://208.199.27.88:5000)

I'm fairly pleased with it so far but the javascript that scrolls the table of contents is a bit laggy. You'll notice it on the live demo if you scroll up and down in the main content area a few times. I'd like know what I can to do make it a lot snappier. Also, when scrolling quickly to the top and bottom, the table of contents doesn't accurately reflect the user is at the top and bottom of the document. Here is the relevant js from the demo:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elems = $('.scrollspy');
    elems.each(function(index){
      var elemTop   = $(this).offset().top;
      var elemBottom   = elemTop + $(this).height();
      if(currentTop + 2 >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom){ // pad by 2px to ensure active
        var id     = $(this).attr('name');
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
        navElem.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
        var dft = navElem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top; // distance from top of viewport
        var s = $('#sidebar');
        if (dft > s.innerHeight() * .5 || dft < s.scrollTop() ) {
          $('#sidebar').animate({
              scrollTop: navElem.offset().top - s.offset().top + s.scrollTop() - s.innerHeight()/2,
              duration: 1,
              ease: 'linear',
          });
        }
      }
    })

});
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the function gets called every time the main contents are scrolled which is inefficient. I'm not sure what I can try to mitigate this.

Comment: One technic can be "throttling". Read more here https://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#throttle

Comment: Just remove the transition time for scrolling, and you're done...

Comment: @BuggyParadox I had eliminated the `animate` method but it was a little to jarring and disorienting. Was hoping to keep the slick scrolling effect.

Comment: I will check into lodash as a last resort. But would rather see if I can avoid another plugin. One thing that might speed things up is storing the elements in an array after the page loads and that way the js doesn't have to search for them every time.

Comment: Yeah, throwing them into an array outside of the function definitely helped. Not perfect, but better.

Comment: Another trick that seems to help is that I shrunk the size of the detectable links with `var elemBottom - elemTop + $(this).height() - 10;` So the scroll action is triggered less frequently.

Comment: A third trick I did was to bail out of the function unless at least 8 microseconds has passed. I'm not so sure about this one as it could be highly dependent on the performance of the end user's browser. Passing through a `.spyscroll` class may not register on slow machines.

Comment: I got rid of the `siblings().removeClass` bit. Didn't seem to help all that much.

Comment: Junking `$(this).height" made a really big difference. It's pretty snappy now.

Comment: @StevieD I'm not advocating for lodash, I'm advocating for throttling. You can write your own function in a couple of lines.

Comment: Yeah, I think I actually did it with timestamps but it didn't seem to help too too much. I ended up pretty much rewriting the algorithm so it doesn't rely on scroll detection. Posting answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. I call a function every 4/10ths of second instead of detecting scrolls. The function checks the current position against the positions of the elements which are calculated just once before the function is called so it's much quicker. Things are very snappy now. Code is a bit of a mess but seems to do the trick.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  autoscroll();
}, 400);
var elems = $('.scrollspy');
var headers = {};
var headers_pos = [];
elems.each(function(index){
  var pos = $(this).position().top - 70;

  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  pos_str = Math.floor(pos);
  headers[pos_str] = name;
  headers_pos.push(pos_str);
});
headers_pos.sort(function(a, b) {return a-b});
var current_active = $("#sidebar a:first");
current_active.addClass('active');

function autoscroll() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#content').offset().top,
        distance = Math.abs(elementOffset - scrollTop);

    var id;
    var last = $('#sidebar a:first').attr('href');
    headers_pos.forEach(function(index) {
      if (index > distance) {
        id = last;
        return;
      } else {
        last = '#' + headers[index];
      }
    });
    if (!id) {
      id = last;
    }


    var navElem = $('a[href="' + id + '"]');
    navElem.addClass('active')
    if (!current_active.is(navElem)) {
      current_active.removeClass( 'active' );
    }
    current_active = navElem;
    var dft = navElem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top; // distance from top of viewport
    var s = $('#sidebar');
    if (dft > s.innerHeight() * .5 || dft < s.scrollTop() ) {
      $('#sidebar').animate({
            scrollTop: navElem.offset().top - s.offset().top + s.scrollTop() - s.innerHeight()/2,
            duration: 1,
            ease: 'swing',
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that breaks this code is if the user resizes the font in the browser by zooming in or out. Is there a way to detect this event with js?